# Form controls on protected sheet

Tags: excel, vba

There is a legacy file with a protected sheet with buttons to run macros. Buttons when pressed execute the macros but I need to know which button execute which macros. Right clicking is not working as the sheet is protected neither enabling the design mode does. How to get this information? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Even if a sheet is protected, you can see the VBA code... Do you know what type of button it is? If an ActiveX, it will keep the code in the sheet code module where it exist. Just right clicking on the sheet name and choosing `View Code` you can access and modify its code. If a Form button having an assigned macro, it can be in any module and you must search for it, putting break points when the sub name may match with what the code does... Of course, if the VBA Project is not protected, too. Even if its protection is not something really safe...

Comment: Thankyou, if it were activex it would have been easier...these are form controls and I am not able to guess which macro gets fired initially when a particular button is pressed....there are many buttons and many macros and the macros are calling each other....seems out of luck :(  btw, vba is unprotected

Comment: There is not standard method to do that. If inside of the macro to be called would be something as `Application.Caller` it will be easy. But I do  not think that what the button does cannot lead to a narrow range of guessing some macros name... It should be somehow connected to the button caption, I think. If not something confidential, can you share the workbook in discussion?

Comment: Thankyou but it's a confidential file :(

Comment: No problem with me. I do  not like looking in workbooks belonging to somebody else. I just wanted to try helping. I wish you succes!

Comment: Thanks for your help...actually this file doesn't belong to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe start with somethingl ike this?

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet, shp

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each shp In ws.Shapes
        Debug.Print ws.Name, shp.Name, shp.OnAction
    Next shp
Next ws
```